# Проблема с переходом по ссылке внутри события. React

Tags: reactjs

Всем доброго дня. Помогите пожалуйста, я новичок в reacte. Мне нужно сделать переход по ссылке внутри сайта, при нажатии на кнопку. Url-a меняется, но перехода не происходит, что я делаю не так? Вот мой код.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styles from './nails.module.scss';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Nails extends Component {

  handler = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/order');
  };


  render() {
    return(<div>
        <div>
          <p>Педикюр</p>
          <p>1ч.</p>
          <p>700р.</p>
            <button onClick={this.handler}>Записаться</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Маникюр + педикюр</p>
          <p>1 ч. 30 мин.</p>
          <p>1300р.</p>
          <button>Записаться</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Маникюр + гель</p>
          <p>45 мин.</p>
          <p>1200р.</p>
          <button>Записаться</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Маникюр</p>
          <p>45 мин.</p>
          <p>700р.</p>
          <button>Записаться</button>
        </div>
    </div>)
  }
}

export default withRouter(Nails);
```

Comment: нужно посмотреть ваши роуты. прикрепите их к задаче

Comment: function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {/* <div className="App">
      </div> */}
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage}/>
          <Route path='/onlineRegistration' component={OnlineRegistration}/>
          <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
          <Route path='/order' component={Order}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: как сделать, чтобы было читаемо, как код? не вижу кнопки для исправления

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Вот как нужно сделать, чтобы все работало.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styles from './nails.module.scss';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class Nails extends Component {
  handler(){
    window.location.assign('http://localhost:3000/order');
  };


  render() {
    return(<div>
        <div>
          <p>Педикюр</p>
          <p>1ч.</p>
          <p>700р.</p>
          <button onClick={(e) => this.handler(e)}>Записаться</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Маникюр + педикюр</p>
          <p>1 ч. 30 мин.</p>
          <p>1300р.</p>
          <button>Записаться</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Маникюр + гель</p>
          <p>45 мин.</p>
          <p>1200р.</p>
          <button>Записаться</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Маникюр</p>
          <p>45 мин.</p>
          <p>700р.</p>
          <button>Записаться</button>
        </div>
    </div>)
  }
}

export default Nails;
```

Comment: нет, так делать не нужно, используйте для этого `react-router-dom`